# Submit button to appear after fb login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, facebook

Is it possible to have a similar button like the one in this sample?
[sample form](http://www.jotform.com/form/12253210329)

I have a multistep form in my site that can be accessed by non-logged in users. They can fill up the form, but to submit the inputs on the form, they will be required to Login with their Username and Password or another option is to Login with Facebook to submit the form.

The form inputs will be associated to a user account so I have a function that when the button for Login with Facebook is clicked, it will create a new row in user table if its new user and will save fb uid, fb name and email. Now I'm lacking the part on how to go on and submit the form inputs or how to make the site recognize the user as a registered member after saving their details and without leaving the form.

Comment: Are you able to save the fb details in your user table

Comment: Yes. I just need to save the form inputs also. The form is not really for user registration so this inputs goes to a different table.

Comment: If you could the save the user details then what made you trouble in gettting the site recongnize the user as a registered member.

Comment: The user info only gets saved when the button is clicked, problem is I need to reload the page for the site to recognize the user. Cant reload as it will lose the form inputs.